# Running regsvr32 from a batch file isn't working

Tags: windows, batch-file, regsvr32

I have created a batch file that goes to a series of application directories and registers all dll and ocx files within them. If I open an elevated command prompt and change to a specific directory and type in the regsvr command manually it works fine. The batch file looks like it is trying to register each file, but they do not get registered. I have tried right clicking on it and tell it to run as administrator (the command window does not show "Administrator" in the title bar), but it doesn't register. If I open an elevated command window and try to run the batch file from there, it doesn't work either.

I have also tried putting the script file in c:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and nothing has worked.

I also read that the file needed to be ANSI instead of Unicode, but that didn't help either.

Is there some sort of command I can put on the line with regsvr that will force each one to be elevated? I don't want to make the user type all the commands in manually.

Here is my batch file:

```
chdir c:\program files (x86)\pfps
for /r %%i in (*.dll) do regsvr32 /s %%i
chdir DataManager
for /r %%i in (*.dll) do regsvr32 /s %%i
chdir ..\falcon
for /r %%i in (*.dll) do regsvr32 /s %%i
for /r %%i in (*.ocx) do regsvr32 /s %%i
chdir FVOverlays
for /r %%i in (*.dll) do regsvr32 /s %%i
chdir ..\..\FVImageryService
for /r %%i in (*.dll) do regsvr32 /s %%i
chdir ..\GarminGPSFeed
for /r %%i in (*.dll) do regsvr32 /s %%i
chdir ..\MapDataServer
for /r %%i in (*.dll) do regsvr32 /s %%i
chdir ..\SkyViewNG
for /r %%i in (*.dll) do regsvr32 /s %%i
for /r %%i in (*.ocx) do regsvr32 /s %%i
chdir ..\System
for /r %%i in (*.dll) do regsvr32 /s %%i
for /r %%i in (*.ocx) do regsvr32 /s %%i
```

Comment: Try quotes: `for /r %%i in (*.dll) do regsvr32 /s "%%i"`.

Comment: That was the trick! What do the quotes do that make it work?

Comment: Path enclosed with doublequotes is threated as single path, even if it contain spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem are the spaces in your path: `c:\program files (x86)\pfps`. The `regsvr32` command will separate on spaces and read that as multiple arguments.

To allow spaces you have to use quotes:

```
for /r %%i in (*.dll) do regsvr32 /s "%%i"
```

leading to e.g.:

```
regsvr32 "c:\program files (x86)\pfps\blahblah.dll"
```

where the path to the file is handled as single argument for `regsvr32`.

---

Why does: `chdir c:\program files (x86)\pfps` work with spaces and without quotes?

It's explained [here on ss64 about `cd/chdir`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html):

> If [Command Extensions](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) are enabled [default] the CD command is enhanced as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> CD does not treat spaces as delimiters, so it is possible to CD into a subfolder name that contains a space without surrounding the name with quotes.
>
> For example:
>   cd \My folder
>
> is the same as:
>   cd "\My folder"
>
> [...]
>
> CHDIR is a synonym for CD

But I recommend always using quotes for paths.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you!